# Download all files and folders in the specific folder in Google Drive which is shared by other account

Tags: backup, google-drive

Is there any way to download all files and folders in the specific folder in Google Drive which is shared by other account? I have tried [goodls](https://github.com/tanaikech/goodls), but it can not download folders and files shared by other account. I need this to make a local backup of Google Drive folder.

Comment: You can log into your Google Drive using a browser and download multiple files as a .zip archive.

Comment: Can't you use your browser?

Comment: I can't use browser. The size of folder is very big and some files cannot be downloaded due to a network error (in google chrome). And i need make backup of this folder every week. So i'm looking for an automatic way.